# Regex to capture a group, but only if preceded by a string and followed by a string

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

There's a few examples of the 'typical' solution to the problem, here in SO and elsewhere, but we need help with a slightly different version.

We have a string such as the following

```
pies
bob likes,
larry likes,
harry likes
cakes
```

And with the following regexp

```
(?<=pies\n|\G,\n)(\w+ likes)
```

Only when the string commences with pies we can capture the 'nnn likes' as expected, however, we'd also need that the capture fails if it doesn't end with 'cakes', and our attempts at doing so have failed.

Link to the regex101: https://regex101.com/r/uDNWXN/1/

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean you want `(?s)(?<=^pies\n(?!.*\ncakes$)|\G,\n)(\w+ likes)`?

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work properly as a php regexp, nothing is captured when tested against the given string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding an extra lookahead at the start, to make sure there is `cakes` in the string:

```
(?s)(?<=\G(?!^),\n|pies\n(?=.*?cakes))(\w+ likes)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CnxYWn/7) (no match as expected, add some char on the last line to have a match).

**Pattern details**

- `(?s)` - DOTALL/singleline modifier to let `.` match any chars including line breaks
- `(?<=` - a positive lookbehind that requires the following immediately to the left of the current location:

  - `\G(?!^),\n` - right after the end of previous match, a comma and then a newline
  - `|`  - or
  - `^pies\n(?=.*cakes)` - start of string, `pies`, newline not followed with any 0+ chars as many as possible, and then a `cakes` string
- `)` - end of the lookbehind
- `(\w+ likes)` - Group 1: any one or more letters, digits or underscores and then a space and `likes`.

Comment: thanks but unless we've not explained the problem properly, this doesn't work as expected.
We need to capture all the 'nnn likes', but only when the ENTIRE string starts with 'pies' and ends with 'cakes'

Comment: @Itaca `(?s)(?<=\G(?!^),\n|^pies\n(?=.*\ncakes$))\w+ likes`? See https://regex101.com/r/CnxYWn/4

Comment: Thanks. With your help we came up with a slightly simpler regexp that covers all our use cases
__(?<=pies\n|\G,\n)(?=.*?cakes)(\w+ likes)__

Comment: @Itaca It is best practice to use `\G` as the first alternative, since the `^pies` will only need to be checked once. Same with `(?=.*cakes)`, no need to check for it every time, you only need to do it once. Also, `\G` matches at the start of a string, to only match a position after the previous successful match, you *must* add `(?!^)` / `(?!\A)` there. Please bear in mind that your simplifications should go in line with your pattern requirements.